# Generating function of number of partitions of $n$ into parts at most $k$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I am trying to grasp the intuition behind this example.

> Show that $\sum_{n \geq 0} p_{\leq k}(n)x^n = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-x^i}$
> where $p_{\leq k}(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of the integer
> $n$ into parts of size at most $k$.

The book *A Walk Through Combinatorics* starts off the solution by determining the coefficients of $x^n$ on the right hand side, but I am not really sure how this helps our case. Are we supposed to show that the coefficients of $x^n$ on the right hand side shows the integer partition of $n$ with parts at most $k$?

If so, my question is:

> What should one show to prove that the coefficients of $x^n$ demonstrates
> an integer partition of $n$ with parts no greater than $k$? What do we need to show that we can finally say "coefficients indeed demonstrate an integer partition of $n$ with parts at most $k$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the product as

> \begin{align*}
> \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-x^i}&=\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\\
> &\qquad\cdot \left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\\
> &\qquad\cdots\\
> &\qquad\cdot \left(1+x^k+x^{2k}+\cdots\right)
> \end{align*}
> where each factor $\left(1+x^j+x^{2j}+\cdots\right)$ with $1\leq j\leq k$ represents zero, one or more occurrences of a part $j$. We observe the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product provides the number of occurrences to select zero, one or more parts of size $1$ to $k$ which sum up to $n$.

We conclude
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n \geq 0} p_{\leq k}(n)x^n = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-x^i}}
\end{align*}

**Example:**
We look at an example with small values $n=5$ and $k=4$. Denoting with $[x^n]$ the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series we get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^5]\prod_{i=1}^4 \frac{1}{1-x^i}}
&=[x^5]\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot \left(1+x^3+x^{6}+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^4+x^{8}+\cdots\right)\\
&=[x^5]\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)\left(1+x^3\right)\left(1+x^4\right)\\
&=[x^5]\left(x^5\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1+x^3x^2\cdot1\cdot1+x^2\cdot1\cdot x^3\cdot1\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+x^1x^4\cdot1\cdot1
+1\cdot1\cdot x^2x^3\cdot1+x^1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot x^4\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=6}
\end{align*}
corresponding to the $6$ representations of $5$ with parts $1\leq k\leq 4$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{5}&\color{blue}{=1+1+1+1+1}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+1+1+2}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+1+3}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+2+2}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+1+3}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+4}
\end{align*}